# How to get proper number of vertices in OBJ file from DCC tools such as Blender for use in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, blender-2.50

I am told that for a simple cube I need 36 vertices when I want to have colors/textures etc. for OpenGL ES application but when I export the colored cube to OBJ format using Blender, I only get 8 vertices and also I  don't even get color data in the OBJ not to mention I only get 8 normals in OBJ file but I need normal for each vertex in each triangle ( a total of 36 normals).

This is what I get as the content of the OBJ file for a cube that has been colored with different colors on all the faces:

```
# Blender v2.56 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib untitled.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.999999 1.000000
v 0.999999 -1.000001 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
vn 0.666646 0.666646 0.333323
vn 0.408246 0.408246 -0.816492
vn -0.408246 0.816492 -0.408246
vn -0.666646 0.333323 0.666646
vn -0.577349 -0.577349 -0.577349
vn -0.577349 -0.577349 0.577349
vn 0.816492 -0.408246 -0.408246
vn 0.333323 -0.666646 0.666646
usemtl Material
s 1
f 5//1 1//2 4//3
f 5//1 4//3 8//4
f 3//5 7//6 8//4
f 3//5 8//4 4//3
f 2//7 6//8 3//5
f 6//8 7//6 3//5
f 1//2 5//1 2//7
f 5//1 6//8 2//7
f 5//1 8//4 6//8
f 8//4 7//6 6//8
f 1//2 2//7 3//5
f 1//2 3//5 4//3
```

This is the content of MTL file:

```
# Blender MTL File: ''
# Material Count: 1
newmtl Material
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

36 vertices for a cube is not right. Possible but unnecessary.

A **vertex** is a kind of coordinate in space, consisting of 3 parameters, x, y, z.
 As a cube has 8 corners then there should be 8 vertices only.

Following vertices, there are **texture coordinates** which is obtained after UV mapping in Blender.

After texture coordinates, there are **indices**. They are the order of connecting vertices which determines in what order your cube is drawn.

And at last, there are **normals** for lighting effects.

While exporting in Blender, make sure you highlight only those:

**Context**:
all scenes

**Output Options**:
triangulate, materials, UVs, normals, HQ

**Blender objects as OBJ**:
objects

This gives you two files: **OBJ** and **MTL**

MTL contains texture image info 
and OBJ contains:

**vertices** in form of:
v   x, y, z
v   x, y, z

**texture coordinates** in form of:
vt  x, y
vt  x, y

**indices** in form of:
f  i/j  k/l  m/n
f  i/j  k/l  m/n

After you successfully get your exported OBJ and MTL files, add them to your project with the texture image and use OpenGLOBJLoader class to render them in iOS.

Comment: I selected those options you specified but I am still getting 8 vertices and 8 normals. I posted the content of the files.

Comment: it looks like you have no texture on your model.

Comment: @erkanyildiz Do you might know how to find/delete the lines? I'm getting i.e. 'l 5396 5386' in an exported obj file.